# Value assignment and return variable in same line

Tags: javascript

I have following code

```
var s = storage('foo');
s.bar = 100;
storage('foo', s);
```

`storage` returns an object from some storage media. I then change the value of one property of the object and send it to `storage` again. My question is is there any way to make it a one liner? Something like

```
storage('foo', storage('foo').bar = 100);
```

But the above code only saves `100` instead of entire `foo` object.

Here is the `storage` function, it stores on localstorage but makes it object storage instead of string storage:

```
function storage(item, value) {
    if(value!=null) {
        var result = (storage()) ? storage() : {};
        if(item) result[item] = value;
        return localStorage.setItem('storage', JSON.stringify(result))
    } else return (item) ? storage()[item] : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storage'));
}
```

Edit:
So I ended up with following one line change in storage function. But this does not account for multidimensional usage. So I will welcome any suggestions.

```
function storage(item, value, property) {
    ...
        if(item) (property) ? result[item][property] = value : result[item] = value;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasonably thing to do, if you cannot change the `storage` function, is to create another function:

```
function set_storage(obj, prop, val) {
    var s = storage(obj);
    obj[prop] = val;
    storage(obj, s);
}

// usage
set_storage('foo', 'bar', 100);
```

If you can change storage though, this would be an even better way. [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) works similarly.

There are ways to do this in (almost) one line, with the help of the [comma operator *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator),  but it ain't pretty:

```
var s = storage('foo');
storage('foo', (s.bar = 100, s));
```

---

Since you said `storage` is your function, overloading it seems to be a good way. It would go like this:

```
function storage(key, prop, val) {
    var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storage'));

    if(arguments.length === 0) {
        return storage;
    }
    else if (arguments.length === 1) {
        // only one argument passed, return the value with key `key`
        return storage[key];
    }
    else if (arguments.length === 2) {
        // set `key` to `prop` (`prop` contains the actual value)
        storage[key] = prop;
    }
    else {
        // set property `prop` of object in `key` to value `val`
        storage[key][prop] = val;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('storage', JSON.stringify(storage));
}

// Usage

// get `foo`:
var foo = storage('foo');

// set `foo`:
storage('foo', {bar: 42});

// set foo.bar
storage('foo', 'bar', 100);
```

I hope it gives you some idea.

Comment: The last example looks interesting, how does it work? I have a feeling this won't work the same way, right? `storage('foo', (storage('foo').bar = 100, storage('foo')));`

Comment: @Achshar: You are right, it won't. The comma operator evaluates it's operands from left to right and returns the result of the right operand. In your example, you are never writing the changed object back to the storage, since `storage('foo')` reads the unmodified object from storage.

Comment: @FelixKling Hmm in that case I will go with your suggestion and make changes to the storage function itself. Will update code here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As `storage` returns an `object`, theres a (very) good chance you can do*;

```
storage('foo').bar = 100;

console.log(storage('foo').bar); // should give 100.
```

... directly, as objects are "pass by reference"-esque.

---

<sup>* A situation where this would not be the case would be where `storage` returns a *copy* of the object stored, rather than the object itself; therefore any updates you make to the returned object will not have an affect on the object in storage.</sup>

Comment: Storage is my own function, it stores on localstorage but makes it object storage instead of string storage. So i am not sure if that can be done. I will update the question with source of `storage`.

Comment: If you're stringifying and parsing from `localStorage`, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function which accepts a function that changes the object:

```
function changeObject(key, func) {
    var obj = storage(key);
    func(obj);
    storage(key, obj);
}

changeObject('foo', function (s) { s.bar = 100; });
```